# User roles in Java

Tags: java, database, oop, design-patterns

I am building POS system. The think is that I don't know what roles are going to be with what functionality. Here is what I have till now:

- I imagined that I have one main class for javafx primary stage, scene and tabpane. Also, there is each class which extends Tab class for tabPane, and all needed code for that functionality. So each tab is separate.
- On other hand. There is User class which is abstract with basic attributes and abstract method ***tasks()***, and in each concrete user role ( Administrator ) class which extends this abstract class implement this method. In tasks() method I would add in List all tabs class which are needed for that user role.

I want to know if this method for users role is good or bad.
Acctualy I am not satisfied. The reason is ***open-closed*** OOP principle. I am not sure which users role are going to be, so I want to make it dynamic.

- Now, what I have in mind, is that I have only one user for start, and that is Administrator. Then, he and only he can make other user roles and save to database. User role tabs he need, administrator would add while creating user role. This way, you can return and add some new functionality to user role. There is no need to go back to code, and adding new to tasks() method.

My concerne is how to implement this. What should I put in database for tasks, should I put Strings and then in some concrete class to add tasks based on string ( With lots of if statement ), or should I serialize arraylist of tasks and then save to database?

Comment: We could not understand your problem!

Comment: What I understood is that you need to implement multiple user-roles with set of permissions each role, is that right?

Comment: Well, I want to know is this method good or not. Is object serialization recommended or there is better approach?

Comment: Yes, but that permission is actually Tab classes. Tab is part of Java FX, and I need to add more Tab classes to specific user role

Comment: Since java has some good security frameworks they support user roles, you can use any of the `spring-security` or `apache-shiro` to achieve this.

Comment: Yes this is possible! and good method.

Comment: Thank you very much! The think is I am not familiar with spring and I need this for school project, so I don't won't to go deep in, because I have other projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `spring-security` or `apache-shiro`.

In `apache-shiro` you can use annotations like below.

```
@RequiresRole("administrator")
class TabPane{
......
........... 
......
}
```

or

```
class TabPane{
......
........... 

@RequiresRole("administrator")
public void getName(){
.......
}
......
}
```